# Face Recognition in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, face-recognition

I have been working on a project which involves Marilena(project that ports Face Detection part of OPENCV to ActionScript3). Right now I can take the faces and keep them as byteArrays.
I am working on Flash Builder 4.

I want to add Face Recognition part either. I will identify the faces by connecting to a database but I couldnt figure out how to do it without OpenCV on flash.You guys have any idea???

Comment: could you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

this may be the one you are looking for
http://developers.face.com/
http://www.faceapi.com

also this you tube video demonstrate some use
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcEIHjV8xs4&feature=related
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uA8ZXPS6onk&NR=1